# Problem with pipe and redirection, create own shell

Tags: c, shell, pipe, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I'm trying to recreate the shell implementation (`bash --posix`) of "`|`" and "`>`" in c.

But I have trouble to find my problems with `fd`. When I do the following command: `echo heyy | wc > txt.txt | wc` everything is going smoothly but one in two the last `wc` display the good answer `(0 0 0)` or the false answer (result of the previous `wc`).

`t_command` is a list of `cmd`. Each node have a `char **tab` with the command, for example:

```
-first node is: tab[0] = echo , tab[1]=heyy
-third node is: tab[0] = wc
```

etc..

````
{
    int         count;
    t_command   *tmp;

    tmp = all_cmd;
    count = 0;
    while (tmp /* && (tmp->type == WORD || tmp->type == PIPE) */)
    {
        if (tmp->type == WORD)
            count++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return (count);
}


pid_t   fork_pipe(int fd_0, int fd_1)
{
    pid_t   pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        return (-1);
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (fd_0 != 0)
        {
            dup2(fd_0, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd_0);
        }
        if (fd_1 != 1)
        {
            dup2(fd_1, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd_1);
        }
    }
    return (pid);
}



int execute_last(t_command *all_cmd, char **env, int fd_0, int fd_1)
{
    int pid;

    pid = fork_pipe(fd_0, fd_1);
    if (pid == 0)
        ft_exec(env, all_cmd->cmd_to_exec);
    return (0);
}

int execute_pipe(t_command *all_cmd, char **env, int nb_cmd)
{
    int     fd[2];
    int     fd_0;
    int     fd_1;
    int     i;
    pid_t   pid;

    i = 0;
    fd_0 = STDIN_FILENO;
    while (all_cmd && i < nb_cmd - 1)
    {
        
        if (pipe(fd) < 0)
            return (-1);
        if(all_cmd->next && all_cmd->next->type == CHV_R)
        {
            fd_1 = open(all_cmd->next->next->cmd_to_exec[0], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 00777);
            execute_last(all_cmd, env, fd_0, fd_1);
            if (all_cmd->next->next)
                all_cmd = all_cmd->next->next;
            i += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            fd_1 = fd[1];
            pid = fork_pipe(fd_0, fd_1);
            if (pid == 0)
                ft_exec(env, all_cmd->cmd_to_exec);
            close(fd[1]);
            fd_0 = fd[0];
        }
        if (all_cmd && all_cmd->next && all_cmd->next->next)
            all_cmd = all_cmd->next->next;
        i++;
    }
    execute_last(all_cmd, env, fd_0, STDOUT_FILENO);
    wait_pipe(nb_cmd);
    return (0);
} ```
````

Comment: Hi. Can you update you post to provide an [MCVE]?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.